# Supernatural romance book about a soldier cursed to be a statue who needs to find true love to break the curse

Tags: story-identification, books

I have been racking my brain, and I feel like I'm going nuts. I am trying to remember the title of a book I read in the 90s. All I can remember is that it was a supernatural romance. The main character is a soldier (I think) who is cursed to be a statue in a garden by a girl he spurned. He is reanimated and supposed to find true love to break the curse. I think a blue moon is involved, but I am not sure. I think there is another book in the series, but I could be wrong. This is really making me crazy. I think there was a rose on the cover. The girl who cursed him also tries to sabotage his chance at breaking the curse.

Comment: Shades of Rory as the last Centurion from *Doctor Who*.